# How to get the textfield value of each dynamically created cell in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview in which custom cells are created/reused for a lot of rows depending upon type of data encountered(i.e. For Date type , cell's textfield picks up the selected date from datePicker and for enum type , it picks the selected data from dropdown picker). Now there is a button at footer which needs to pick up the data from each cell and process it to display further view controller.

Since data in cells are displayed fine after selection(from datepicker or drop down or keypad) but how can we capture these data in footer button method.

Here is the code :-

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
     return [valueArray count];
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
NSString *values = [valueArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *titles = [titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if([titles isEqualToString:@“enumType”]){
        cell.headerInfo.hidden = true;
        cell.valueObtained.hidden=true;

        UITextField * scheduelText = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 30, 130, 30)];

        NSMutableArray* enumArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [enumArray addObject:@"BUSINESS"];
        [enumArray addObject:@"CUSTODIAL"];
        [enumArray addObject:@"INDIVIDUAL"];

        downPicker = [[DownPicker alloc] initWithTextField:scheduelText enumArray];

        scheduelText.text = downPicker.text;
        [cell addSubview:scheduelText];
    }

else if([titles isEqualToString:@"DateType”]){
        cell.headerInfo.hidden = true;
        cell.valueObtained.hidden=true;

        UITextField  *dateText = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 30, 130, 30)];
        dateText.placeholder=@"Date";
        dateText.inputView = self.datePicker;        

        UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)];
        UIBarButtonItem *doItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dateDoneButton)];
        [toolBar setItems:@[doItem]];

        dateText.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;

        [cell addSubview:dateText];
    }
else if([titles isEqualToString:@“TextType”]){
        cell.headerInfo.hidden = true;
        cell.valueObtained.hidden=true;

        UITextField * accountText = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 30, 130, 30)];
        accountText.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        accountText.delegate = self;
        accountText.placeholder=@"Account Name";
        [accountText setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [accountText setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
        [cell addSubview:accountText];
    }
else{
        cell.valueObtained.text = values;
        cell.headerInfo.text = titles;
    }

    return cell;

}


- (void)submitButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    //Need to capture the cell data here ?


}
```

Please help out in this.

Comment: I really recommend to create custom cell class for that, so you can create a delegate or pass code block for it, else u have to create tag (not recommended) or convert point to cell with `indexPathForRowAtPoint`

Comment: There are two options: TAG and DELEGATE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with your code:

```
[cell addSubview:scheduelText];
[cell addSubview:dateText];
[cell addSubview:accountText];
```

Everytime you dequeue the cell will add a new subview to the cell,but never removed.
In my suggestion,you'd better identifier 4 kind of cells with different identifiers,or removesubviews whenever dequeue the cell.

Comment: Yes Leon, You are right. It is just overriding the previous cell and values are getting lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can set tag for each of the textfield. and get UITextField from tag.

```
 - (void)submitButtonPressed:(id)sender
{

        UITableViewCell *cell =[tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];

        UITextField *txtField =[cell viewWithTag:TAG];

        NSLog(@"%@",txtField.text);
}
```

Also, Please use custom cells for this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using dynamic table view there is only an option. Delegate your controls and store their value on 'endEditing'. You can't use viewTag because view is going to be destroyed if is not visible on screen.
Another option is using static tableview and then you can create @IBOutlets for each control.